# Dynamic parameters to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a problem in creating dynamic parameters to stored procedure. 
I have two `nvarchar` parameters in a stored procedure that are combination of words separated with comma.
For example:

```
    'Login, check, take, return' and 'admin, yes, no, yes'
```

I have to include these parameters in the where clause like

```
    login=admin and check=yes and take=no and return=yes
```

The problem is that the number of words in the parameters are dynamic. It can vary from 1 to 20 words.

Is there any solution to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

- Define 20 parameters with defaults of NULL
- Only set the ones you want
- In the WHERE clause do `(@Param IS NULL or Column = @Param)`

If you have completely dynamic SQL and random parameter names then it's one of

- you shouldn't be using stored procedures
- you need to write more stored procedures for different use cases

You wouldn't have a completely dynamic .net method would you?

Comment: I think using 20 parameters is not a good way and ofcourse I 'm getting those parameters as a comma separated string. Only two parameters are there.

Comment: How ugly do you think parsing a CSV is compared to 20 parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create dynamic SQL Query inside your stored procedure. In stored procedure you have to split your parameter and value and built dynamic where condition.

Comment: Yes I can split both parameters using a function. But where I can save it? Can I save it as an array? How to include it in the where condition.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save in the variable in stored procedure.

E.g.

```
@sql as nvarchar(1000)
@sql = 'select * from tablename where'
```

Now you Loop through ur variable like

```
@sql =  @sql +' '+ @firstvariable + ' = '''+ @valuevariable +'' AND '
```