# Best approach to dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have a task to build a query (just the where clause) and store it in the database.
It will then be executed by a stored proc.

I want to use parametrised dynamic query but it's awkward to store query separate from parameters in the DB, read both in SQL and tie params to the where clause. Awkwardness is in the fact that number and type of parameters is arbitrary.

I don't want unparametrised dynamic SQL for the fact that search values are provided by users and I didn't find a reliable way to protect against SQL injection.

Is there an elegant approach to it?

I'm using .NET and SQL Server.

---

Example of what I am talking about:

```
-- @filterId is passed to the SP

declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'select id, name, otherField from Items where' + whereClause 
           from Filters 
           where id = @filterId

create table #items {
  id int not null,
  name nvarchar(100),
  otherField nvarchar(200)
}

insert into #items exec(@sql)

-- do something with items and return result
```

---

**Edit:** I have been advised to avoid subjective terms in order to get a meaningful response. I believe defining what is "Best" and "Elegant" would do.
So, when I say "Best" I am looking for a solution that is secure, fast, readable and maintainable more that other solutions.
"Elegant" - does exactly the task, with minimum code and without too many assumptions, e.g. if I need to handle arbitrary set of parameters, I don't want to create 20 placeholders for possible parameters or create a table with column for all possible types of parameters and get the right value with coalesce.

Comment: Did you ever read Erland Sommarskogs' [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)?

Comment: There seems to be lots of help [here](https://www.google.com/#q=sql+server+dynamic+stored+procedure).

Comment: I like when moderators do the commenting.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a bad question, but some people have lesser Google skills than I.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6922745/102937

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's just nice seeing so many diamonds getting involved and mingling with the community.

Comment: I may have not made myself clear enough. Having to define fixed set of parameters when calling sp_executesql doesn't strike me as an elegant solution to arbitrary set of parameters.

Comment: It would help if you avoid using subjective terms like "best" and "elegant". What is your actual priority? For example, do you want to write all your own code but make it as readable and maintainable as possible; or do you want to write as little code as possible by using an existing library or framework? Even if you use a full-blown reporting tool like SSRS, it's still building SQL queries behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the one thing you are doing wrong is the

```
exec(@sql)
```

There is nothing wrong per say with instruction itself but you are open to attack from SQL injections.  Someone can very easily put in 'select * from thing DROP TABLE Orders'.  If that person had rights they just dropped your table.  A better method is

```
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

ensuring that @sql is unicode varchar, which you already did in your example.  sp_executesql also takes an options params argument that is even more flexible.

Also keep in mind if you are stating 'I am using .NET' Linq has some pretty cool things it can do with entity framework to abstract the SQL out of database via a model layer and you can also do dynamic Linq.  This offers an abstraction layer to work with overtop of the SQL that is preferable in ways that you can model your data with .NET enumerations and lists as well as run other code from a layer not directly connected to your database through the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah we can use execute @sql in the dynamic query.. When your using dynamic query for dynamic search, build a regex pattern that does not allows the single quotes ' to prevent from sql injection.

Comment: sanitizing input may give you some protection against SQL injection, but not a perfect protection.